# Enable Windows 10 built-in hotspot by cmd/batch/powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, hotspot

I'm searching for a way to enable/disable the Hotspot built into Windows 10 via the command prompt, powershell or a batch file. In the GUI, it can be easily done with the third button in the network panel (see image below), but I want to automate it.

I already found some hundred tutorials how to *create a new* hotspot using `netsh`, but as I understand it this would create another, different hotspot.
Instead I want to use the already configured one. Or does Windows 10 use the same and creates a new hotspot every time but in between only remembers the settings?

[image]

---

I played around a little bit and discovered the following:

1. My current WiFi driver doesn't support hosted networks. If I enter `netsh wlan show drivers` it says `hosted network supprt: no`. So for the 'common' solution I would have to update the driver.
2. Nevertheless, I can create a HotSpot with the built-in solution (see image).
3. It seems that if I activate this HotSpot, Windows creates an additional `Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #x`. As soon I deactivate the HotSpot, the adapter vanishes.

So it seems that MS is using a very different technique for the built-in hotspot than the `netsh` variant. Which brings me again to the question: how can I automate (by script) the enabling/disabling of this hotspot?

Comment: Anything but batch. It would be extremely difficult in pure batch . Use Powershell instead.

Comment: @SteveFest Ok, I don't work long with Win10, so I didn't thought of the Powershell. So how to do it with powershell?

Comment: Sadly I know nothing about PS. But maybe search Google "Powershell enable hotspot"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Hosted Network (which can be configured using the `netsh wlan set hostednetwork ...` command) and the "new" Mobile Hotspot use different technologies under the hood.

There's a WinRT API to control and configure the "new" mobile hotspot you're referring to. You can call it from PowerShell:

The following code snippet requires [Ben N.'s await function for IAsyncOperation and IAsyncAction in PowerShell, which can be found here](https://superuser.com/a/1342416).

```
$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

# Be sure to include Ben N.'s await for IAsyncOperation:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell

# Check whether Mobile Hotspot is enabled
$tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState

# Start Mobile Hotspot
Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])

# Stop Mobile Hotspot
Await ($tetheringManager.StopTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
```

The [NetworkOperatorTetheringManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager) class also allows you to set the SSID and the passphrase of your hotspot programmatically.

Comment: Additionally, this also allows for us to circumvent the problem that the mobile hotspot turns itself off if no clients are connected by simply running a script to turn it on every once in a while, which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: See WinRT example of same, below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833873/enable-win10-inbuild-hotspot-by-cmd-batch-powershell/60444585#answer-60444585

Comment: @GILGAMESH You can stop the Mobile Hotspot from turning itself off if no devices are connected by simply going to: Settings -> Network & Internet -> Mobile Hotspot. Make sure your Mobile Hotspot is turned on (i.e - "Share my internet connection with other devices" is set to "On"). Then, on the bottom of the window, under "Power Saving", make sure "When no devices are connected, automatically turn off mobile hotspot." is set to "Off".

Comment: @Elyasaf755 That's a good suggestion, but even with that setting enabled, I find that the hotspot just likes to halt every so often, possibly related to the connection dropping and reconnecting, which brings me to this answer.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR:**
If anyone is interested, I've created a batch file using the above solution to turn on the Mobile Hotspot. Simply create a new .bat file and paste the following code inside:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -encodedCommand WwBXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAC4AUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBVAHMAZQByAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGUALgBMAG8AYwBrAFMAYwByAGUAZQBuACwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AVQBzAGUAcgBQAHIAbwBmAGkAbABlACwAQwBvAG4AdABlAG4AdABUAHkAcABlAD0AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAF0AIAB8ACAATwB1AHQALQBOAHUAbABsAA0ACgBBAGQAZAAtAFQAeQBwAGUAIAAtAEEAcwBzAGUAbQBiAGwAeQBOAGEAbQBlACAAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0ALgBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAC4AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAA0ACgAkAGEAcwBUAGEAcwBrAEcAZQBuAGUAcgBpAGMAIAA9ACAAKABbAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAEUAeAB0AGUAbgBzAGkAbwBuAHMAXQAuAEcAZQB0AE0AZQB0AGgAbwBkAHMAKAApACAAfAAgAD8AIAB7ACAAJABfAC4ATgBhAG0AZQAgAC0AZQBxACAAJwBBAHMAVABhAHMAawAnACAALQBhAG4AZAAgACQAXwAuAEcAZQB0AFAAYQByAGEAbQBlAHQAZQByAHMAKAApAC4AQwBvAHUAbgB0ACAALQBlAHEAIAAxACAALQBhAG4AZAAgACQAXwAuAEcAZQB0AFAAYQByAGEAbQBlAHQAZQByAHMAKAApAFsAMABdAC4AUABhAHIAYQBtAGUAdABlAHIAVAB5AHAAZQAuAE4AYQBtAGUAIAAtAGUAcQAgACcASQBBAHMAeQBuAGMATwBwAGUAcgBhAHQAaQBvAG4AYAAxACcAIAB9ACkAWwAwAF0ADQAKAEYAdQBuAGMAdABpAG8AbgAgAEEAdwBhAGkAdAAoACQAVwBpAG4AUgB0AFQAYQBzAGsALAAgACQAUgBlAHMAdQBsAHQAVAB5AHAAZQApACAAewANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAkAGEAcwBUAGEAcwBrACAAPQAgACQAYQBzAFQAYQBzAGsARwBlAG4AZQByAGkAYwAuAE0AYQBrAGUARwBlAG4AZQByAGkAYwBNAGUAdABoAG8AZAAoACQAUgBlAHMAdQBsAHQAVAB5AHAAZQApAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACQAbgBlAHQAVABhAHMAawAgAD0AIAAkAGEAcwBUAGEAcwBrAC4ASQBuAHYAbwBrAGUAKAAkAG4AdQBsAGwALAAgAEAAKAAkAFcAaQBuAFIAdABUAGEAcwBrACkAKQANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAkAG4AZQB0AFQAYQBzAGsALgBXAGEAaQB0ACgALQAxACkAIAB8ACAATwB1AHQALQBOAHUAbABsAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACQAbgBlAHQAVABhAHMAawAuAFIAZQBzAHUAbAB0AA0ACgB9AA0ACgBGAHUAbgBjAHQAaQBvAG4AIABBAHcAYQBpAHQAQQBjAHQAaQBvAG4AKAAkAFcAaQBuAFIAdABBAGMAdABpAG8AbgApACAAewANAAoAIAAgACAAIAAkAGEAcwBUAGEAcwBrACAAPQAgACgAWwBTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAuAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAUgB1AG4AdABpAG0AZQBTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQBFAHgAdABlAG4AcwBpAG8AbgBzAF0ALgBHAGUAdABNAGUAdABoAG8AZABzACgAKQAgAHwAIAA/ACAAewAgACQAXwAuAE4AYQBtAGUAIAAtAGUAcQAgACcAQQBzAFQAYQBzAGsAJwAgAC0AYQBuAGQAIAAkAF8ALgBHAGUAdABQAGEAcgBhAG0AZQB0AGUAcgBzACgAKQAuAEMAbwB1AG4AdAAgAC0AZQBxACAAMQAgAC0AYQBuAGQAIAAhACQAXwAuAEkAcwBHAGUAbgBlAHIAaQBjAE0AZQB0AGgAbwBkACAAfQApAFsAMABdAA0ACgAgACAAIAAgACQAbgBlAHQAVABhAHMAawAgAD0AIAAkAGEAcwBUAGEAcwBrAC4ASQBuAHYAbwBrAGUAKAAkAG4AdQBsAGwALAAgAEAAKAAkAFcAaQBuAFIAdABBAGMAdABpAG8AbgApACkADQAKACAAIAAgACAAJABuAGUAdABUAGEAcwBrAC4AVwBhAGkAdAAoAC0AMQApACAAfAAgAE8AdQB0AC0ATgB1AGwAbAANAAoAfQANAAoAJABjAG8AbgBuAGUAYwB0AGkAbwBuAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGUAIAA9ACAAWwBXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAC4ATgBlAHQAdwBvAHIAawBpAG4AZwAuAEMAbwBuAG4AZQBjAHQAaQB2AGkAdAB5AC4ATgBlAHQAdwBvAHIAawBJAG4AZgBvAHIAbQBhAHQAaQBvAG4ALABXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAC4ATgBlAHQAdwBvAHIAawBpAG4AZwAuAEMAbwBuAG4AZQBjAHQAaQB2AGkAdAB5ACwAQwBvAG4AdABlAG4AdABUAHkAcABlAD0AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAF0AOgA6AEcAZQB0AEkAbgB0AGUAcgBuAGUAdABDAG8AbgBuAGUAYwB0AGkAbwBuAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGUAKAApAA0ACgAkAHQAZQB0AGgAZQByAGkAbgBnAE0AYQBuAGEAZwBlAHIAIAA9ACAAWwBXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAC4ATgBlAHQAdwBvAHIAawBpAG4AZwAuAE4AZQB0AHcAbwByAGsATwBwAGUAcgBhAHQAbwByAHMALgBOAGUAdAB3AG8AcgBrAE8AcABlAHIAYQB0AG8AcgBUAGUAdABoAGUAcgBpAG4AZwBNAGEAbgBhAGcAZQByACwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAE4AZQB0AHcAbwByAGsAaQBuAGcALgBOAGUAdAB3AG8AcgBrAE8AcABlAHIAYQB0AG8AcgBzACwAQwBvAG4AdABlAG4AdABUAHkAcABlAD0AVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBSAHUAbgB0AGkAbQBlAF0AOgA6AEMAcgBlAGEAdABlAEYAcgBvAG0AQwBvAG4AbgBlAGMAdABpAG8AbgBQAHIAbwBmAGkAbABlACgAJABjAG8AbgBuAGUAYwB0AGkAbwBuAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGUAKQANAAoADQAKACMAIABCAGUAIABzAHUAcgBlACAAdABvACAAaQBuAGMAbAB1AGQAZQAgAEIAZQBuACAATgAuACcAcwAgAGEAdwBhAGkAdAAgAGYAbwByACAASQBBAHMAeQBuAGMATwBwAGUAcgBhAHQAaQBvAG4AOgANAAoAIwAgAGgAdAB0AHAAcwA6AC8ALwBzAHUAcABlAHIAdQBzAGUAcgAuAGMAbwBtAC8AcQB1AGUAcwB0AGkAbwBuAHMALwAxADMANAAxADkAOQA3AC8AdQBzAGkAbgBnAC0AYQAtAHUAdwBwAC0AYQBwAGkALQBuAGEAbQBlAHMAcABhAGMAZQAtAGkAbgAtAHAAbwB3AGUAcgBzAGgAZQBsAGwADQAKAA0ACgAjACAAQwBoAGUAYwBrACAAdwBoAGUAdABoAGUAcgAgAE0AbwBiAGkAbABlACAASABvAHQAcwBwAG8AdAAgAGkAcwAgAGUAbgBhAGIAbABlAGQADQAKACQAdABlAHQAaABlAHIAaQBuAGcATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAFQAZQB0AGgAZQByAGkAbgBnAE8AcABlAHIAYQB0AGkAbwBuAGEAbABTAHQAYQB0AGUADQAKAA0ACgAjACAAUwB0AGEAcgB0ACAATQBvAGIAaQBsAGUAIABIAG8AdABzAHAAbwB0AA0ACgBBAHcAYQBpAHQAIAAoACQAdABlAHQAaABlAHIAaQBuAGcATQBhAG4AYQBnAGUAcgAuAFMAdABhAHIAdABUAGUAdABoAGUAcgBpAG4AZwBBAHMAeQBuAGMAKAApACkAIAAoAFsAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwAuAE4AZQB0AHcAbwByAGsAaQBuAGcALgBOAGUAdAB3AG8AcgBrAE8AcABlAHIAYQB0AG8AcgBzAC4ATgBlAHQAdwBvAHIAawBPAHAAZQByAGEAdABvAHIAVABlAHQAaABlAHIAaQBuAGcATwBwAGUAcgBhAHQAaQBvAG4AUgBlAHMAdQBsAHQAXQApAA==
```

(Although it's trivial to say, I'll remind you that the above code will also work as a CMD command).


**Explanation:**

What I did is to take the following PowerShell script (given in above answers by [Julius Hardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7006729/julius-hardt)), and convert it to a batch file using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070152/how-to-run-powershell-command-in-batch-file/65911978#65911978) converter:

```
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}
$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

# Be sure to include Ben N.'s await for IAsyncOperation:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell

# Check whether Mobile Hotspot is enabled
$tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState

# Start Mobile Hotspot
Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
```

I've also put this batch file inside the startup folder located in *"C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"* so the Mobile Hotspot will turn on automatically upon Windows startup.

**To toggle the Mobile Hotspot ON\OFF, I've modified the above answer (by [Julius Hardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7006729/julius-hardt)) to this:**

```
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}

$connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
$tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

# Be sure to include Ben N.'s await for IAsyncOperation:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell

# Check whether Mobile Hotspot is enabled
$tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState

# If Mobile Hotspot is on - turn it off.
if ($tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState -eq 1){
    # Stop Mobile Hotspot
    Await ($tetheringManager.StopTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
}
# If Mobile Hotspot is off - turn it on.
else{
    # Start Mobile Hotspot
    Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
}
```

The corresponding batch file:

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -encodedCommand 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
```

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 10 mobile hotspot gets started by the Windows Mobile Hotspot Service (icssvc).
Using Powershell:

Get the current state of the service:

```
get-service "icssvc"
```

Start the service:

```
start-service "icssvc"
```

Stop the service:

```
stop-service "icssvc"
```

If you want to configure the hotspot then thats another thing. You can Google "Configure Internet Connection Sharing with PowerShell" to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I see, the service gets started when I activate the hotspot or go to the configuration page, BUT unfortunately its not vice versa: when I start the service the hotspot doesn't get started.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the PowerShell comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833873/enable-win10-inbuild-hotspot-by-cmd-batch-powershell/60444585#answer-55563418),

Here are the WinRT code components for mix/match to accomplish the above tasks for WiFi Direct 2.0 HotSpot activities using C++ without dependencies on other tooling etc (they work on IoT Core, etc):

- Programmatically set the **SSID** and/or **PassPhrase**
- Programmatically query the current WiFi Direct 2.0 HotSpot **status**
- Programmatically turn **on/off** the WiFi Direct 2.0 HotSpot

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Connectivity.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.h>
namespace winrt { // /ZW embed in :<winrt> when `Windows` is ambiguously defined
  static void af_winrt_wifi_hotspot_test() {
    // start ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot
    init_apartment(); // apartment_type::multi_threaded
    auto connectionProfile { Windows::Networking::Connectivity::NetworkInformation::GetInternetConnectionProfile() };
    auto tetheringManager = Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::NetworkOperatorTetheringManager::CreateFromConnectionProfile(connectionProfile);
    switch(tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState()) {
      case Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::TetheringOperationalState::Off: {
          auto ioAsync = tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync();
          auto fResult = ioAsync.get();
        }
        break;
      case Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::TetheringOperationalState::On: {
          auto ioAsync = tetheringManager.StopTetheringAsync();
          auto fResult = ioAsync.get();
        }
        break;
      case Windows::Networking::NetworkOperators::TetheringOperationalState::InTransition:
      default:
        break;
    }
    clear_factory_cache();
    uninit_apartment();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm @smallscript's winRT solution works. Running the script will either open/close hotspot connection depends on the current status (enabled to disabled and vice versa).

To complete his answer I will point out two additional things in order to compile the code:

- You must have Windows SDK installed(I used version 10.0.18362.0) to have the winRT library.
- You need to link the RuntimeObject.lib library to your project, otherwise you'll get unresolved external symbols (Using VS, Add the name to: Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution at the moment is to setup an autohotkey script to click the button on start up. Windows +A, Shift Tab, down arrow, etc...  I need this for a headless PC to allow wifi remote desktop.

Comment: After some testing as much as autohotkey looked to have worked, in my case at bootup and there is no internet connection initially, the hotspot box is disabled so it will not activate.   If later the initial internet is lost, the hotspot remains working however this is a chicken/egg scenario...  I may use this as a backup but I need a temporary router connect originally to make the first connection.  Then you can activate the hotspot and continue.  Then if the initial router fails you can still access the machine through hotspot.  Warning:  I believe the hotspot will deactivate if no activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shortcut in “C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp” to hotspot.bat so that wi-fi is set to on when the machine boots up. Or, run hotspot.bat on its own to toggle wi-fi between on and off.

hotspot.bat

```
REM no administrator privileges are needed
REM PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
PowerShell -file <where this file is>\\hotspot.ps1
```

hotspot.ps1

```
# from https://superuser.com/a/1434648
# altered to perform a simple toggle based on tether state
# which is a value of "On" or "Off" not 0 or 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]


Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType)
{
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}

Function ToggleHotspot()
{
    $connectionProfile = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation,Windows.Networking.Connectivity,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::GetInternetConnectionProfile()
    $tetheringManager = [Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringManager,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::CreateFromConnectionProfile($connectionProfile)

    $connectionProfile
    $tetheringManager

    if ($tetheringManager.TetheringOperationalState -eq "On")
    {
        "Stopping Hotspot"
        Await ($tetheringManager.StopTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
    }
    else
    {
        "Starting Hotspot"
        Await ($tetheringManager.StartTetheringAsync()) ([Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorTetheringOperationResult])
    }
}

ToggleHotspot
```

Answer (score -3):

By Using CMD.
It is too Simple to turn PC as Hotspot. But you PC must have Hosted network supported, to check it out try this command

```
    @echo off
REM    Copyright (C) 2013  
REM    user49828
REM
REM    Batch file for creating Wifi Hotspot
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload
    echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    rem put your code here
    rem e.g.: perl myscript.pl %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
    :start
@ECHO off
ECHO  Pleae select one of the options Programmed By Overflown.com  "user49828"
ECHO  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO  1 Hotspot settings
ECHO  2 Start Hotspot
ECHO  3 Stop  Hotspot
ECHO  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET /p option=Please enter one of the options:

if %option%==1  ( goto setup )      else set /a er=1
if %option%==2  ( goto start1 )      else set /a er=er+1
if %option%==3  ( goto stop )       else set /a er=er+1

:noOption
if %er% GEQ 3 ( 
Echo Error!
Echo Please enter a correct option
@pause
cls  
goto start
)

:setup
SET /p ssid=Please enter the Hotspot name:
SET /p key=Please enter the Hotspot password greater the 8 digits:
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%ssid% key=%key% 
if %errorlevel%==0 (
ECHO Setup complete
)
@pause
cls  
goto start

:start1
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
@pause
cls  
goto start

:stop
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
@pause
cls  
goto start
goto :eof
```

Comment: Sorry, but that was the answer I explicitly didn't asked for - I already found this. My question was how to enable/disable the inbuild hotspot (see image)

Comment: @casiosmu it seemed user49828 confused "enable" and "create new".

Comment: I have Edited my answer with proper solutions Check it out please vote my answer and flag it.

Answer (score -3):

Turn on command - netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow

Turn off command - netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow

-not tested-