# How to programmatically detect Mobile Hotspot setting in Win10?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a windows API or maybe through registry setting to detect if Mobile HotSpot is enabled/disabled?

I am writing a win32 app that checks if the hotspot setting is enabled/disabled.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if [this Q&A is a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45833873/1270789) as it discusses PowerShell mostly, but there is a lot of useful information to give you hints where to look for an API - [this seems to be the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkoperatortetheringmanager.tetheringoperationalstate?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Networking_NetworkOperators_NetworkOperatorTetheringManager_TetheringOperationalState).

Comment: Thanks. The API seem to be for WinRT. I am writing a win32 app so I am not sure how to integrate it.

Comment: [NetworkOperatorTetheringManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkoperatortetheringmanager) has the `DualApiPartition` attribute set. There's nothing that keeps you from using it from a desktop application.