# How to set up Windows 10 Mobile Hotspot programmatically?

Tags: powershell, winapi, networking, network-programming, windows-10

Windows 10 introduced the [Mobile Hotspot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot) service:

[image: Mobile Hotspot Settings]

How to enable it, set the SSID and password programmatically, using PowerShell or Windows API?

**Note:** I am not talking about the Hosted Network service (i.e. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Name key=Passphrase`). The Mobile Hotspot service works even if a network card does not support Hosted Network.

Comment: See also: [Getting Your Apps Connected with Networking APIs](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-86)

Comment: **See this explanation, solution w/code:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829382/wlanhostednetworkstartusing-or-how-windows-10-builtin-mobile-hotspot-works/50712007#answer-50712007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have found so far using Process Monitor is that Mobile Hotspot is managed by the `icssvc` service and SSID and password are stored as binary data under registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icssvc\Settings\PrivateConnectionSettings`.

Comment: Any more info on this?  The NetSH command now requires admin privileges in Windows 10 1803 (April 2018) and hoping to find some way to start a mobile hotspot programatically that doesn't require admin elevation.

Comment: @AlexUT Have a look at [Getting Your Apps Connected with Networking APIs](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-86) and [NetworkOperatorTetheringManager Class](http://aka.ms/tetheringmsdn).